# How can I sync Yahoo Calendar on my phone?

Tags: sync, calendar

I want to sync my Yahoo! Calendar on my phone. An article on Yahoo!'s help page seems to suggest that [the only way to access it is by viewing their mobile website in a browser](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SLN5932&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1358304125426&locale=en_US&y=PROD_MAIL_ML). I've tried adding the iCal link provided by Yahoo! Calendar in my Google Calendar account, but Google seems to be unable to fetch the contents of my calendar.

What other options do I have to sync my Yahoo! Calendar on my phone - either within the stock calendar app, or using a third-party application? (In case of a third-party application, it would be nice if it 'looks good' and/or comes with widgets.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just downloaded [CalDAV-Sync beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.caldav.lib) and it took some fooling around, but seems to be working now.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. There seems to be a problem with Yahoo!'s CalDAV sync servers which prevents some accounts from using this particular app for background sync.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you could use to sync your Yahoo! calendar with your android device.

1. Using a `CSV` file. 
   You can export your yahoo calendar to a CSV file and import it into your google calendar. This method is somewhat manual and you will have to do this each time you create an event in your yahoo calendar. [More details](http://www.ehow.com/how_8486671_sync-yahoo-calendar-droid.html)
2. Use Yahoo! app for android
   You can use the official app for android developed by yahoo inc. to access your yahoo calendar as well as your mail, news, IM, videos and more. Download from the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.yahoo)
3. Use third party apps to calendar syncing
   There are many apps in tur play store which can be used to do this. [CalcSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.examp.caldav_y&hl=en) is an app which syncs yahoo caoendar with the stock calendar.

Comment: The csv option will not sync, it will only be a one time import. CalSync seems like a good option as it syncs with the existing calendar. Another option is [CalDav-Sync+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.examp.caldav&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmV4YW1wLmNhbGRhdiJd) it supports yahoo and others. from the same developer as CalSync.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, however, I use yahoos webhosting for my own domain.  You can not sync, nor view domains the mobile site or app.

I actually had to move to googles calendar.  Bad thing is reminders only show up in your google email.  So I had to set a email filter in gmail that will forward all google calendar email reminders to my other domain.

This is working but a pain to set up.

Answer (score 1):

I use a calendar app called aCalendar and sync it to my Yahoo calendar with another app called SmoothSync.  You have to set up both apps once, but then SmoothSync runs in the background and syncs aCalendar (or the native calendar app) with Yahoo.  It has worked very well for me.

Comment: Could you at least add links?

Answer (score 1):

Use Jorte Calendar on your Android.  It will sync with Yahoo Calendar.

Play Store links:

- [Jorte Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.johospace.jorte)
- [Jorte Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.jorte.sync)

Answer (score 1):

Try [SolCalendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.daum.android.solcalendar). It worked for my Droid phone.